# How to analyze this type of queue

Tags: probability, markov-process, queueing-theory

The setup is as follows:

Families arrive at a taxi stand according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. An arriving family finding $N$ other families waiting for a taxi does not wait. Taxis arrive at the taxi stand according to a Poisson process with rate $\mu$. A taxi finding $M$ other taxis waiting does not wait. Derive expressions for the proportion of time are there no families waiting, and the proportion of time are there no taxis waiting.

From what I have learned so far, this appears to me to be a $M/M/c/K$ queue, where there are $c$ servers (taxis) and system capacity $K$ (since there are at most $N$ families in line). Then when finding the proportion of time are there no taxis waiting, the taxis would become the "customers" and the families the "servers". However, the $M/M/c/K$ queue has the condition that $c\leq K$, which is not specified in this question. I am wondering if I may proceed as if it were an $M/M/c/K$ queue in both scenarios, then find the balance equations to derive $\pi_0$ in both case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I think you could rewrite the question to an $M/M/1$ queue with capacity $N+M$ and baulking, saying something like:

> Customers arrive at a queue according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. A customer finding $N+M$ other customers waiting does not wait. Service times are exponentially distributed with rate parameter $\mu$. Derive expressions for the proportion of time are there are $M$ or fewer customers waiting, and the proportion of time there are $M$ or more customers waiting.

Comment: Thanks. I have derived $\pi_j$ in this $M/M/1/N+M$ scenario, then found $\sum_{j=0}^M \pi_j$ to answer the first part, and $\sum_{j=M}^{N+M} \pi_j$ for the second. I am wondering though how to define a "customer" in this setting though: would it still be the families arriving or would it be the pairing of a taxi with a family?

Comment: Here I think having $k$ customers in the queue would be the equivalent of having $k-M$ families waiting if $k\ge M$, or of $M-k$ taxis waiting if $k \le M$